# How to send a String parameter to resteasy and conver to json?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

i would like to send a single String in payload, like this:

```
{
  "value":"myvalue"
}
```

In my method i will receive a single String value, not a object.

Is possible to resteasy take only the "myvalue", with no mapping?

Thanks !

Comment: Why is `myObject.getValue()` not possible ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use model classes? The objects will be converted to and from by the framework

Comment: Is a method that update only one field of model...is a PUT to one field, im not sending all object.

Comment: Sure why not. You can have a class with only one attribute. Other wise you will need to use the JSON Processing API, which I a bit more complicated than just creating a model class

Comment: Right, if i have a class that i can map only this attribute seams better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Couple Options

- Use the [JSON Processing API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html). Something like:

  ```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postJson(String json) {
        String value = null;
        try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json))) {
            JsonObject object = reader.readObject();
            JsonValue jsonValue = object.get("value");
            value = jsonValue.toString();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        return Response.created(newUri).build();
    }
  ```
- Create a model class and let the JAX-RS framework handle the binding for you. It will read Json into your object and write it back out as Json

  ```
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Demo {
        // Should be same same as key (or we need annotations)
        private String value;
        public String getValue() { return value; }
        public void setValue(String value) {this.value = value;}
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postJson(Demo demo) {
        System.out.println(demo.getValue());
        return Response.created(newUri).build();
    }
  ```

---

### UPDATE

Looking at your comment, you say you want to PUT just a field. Generally, you GET a representation, and PUT the *entire* representation back to the server. But if this is too cumbersome (i.e. large representations), you may want to look into [**PATCH**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789). Though not directly supported by JAX-RS, we are allowed to create our own Http method annotations

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
public @interface PATCH{}
```

Just annotation your resource method with this, and you can send requests through the PATCH method. An example Client API request might look something like

```
client.target(location).request().method("PATCH",Entity.xml(patchObject));
```